# Issues parsing a MIDI file with a C program

Tags: c, arrays, hex, buffer, midi

I'm writing a MIDI file parser for a class. I'm reading in values byte by byte and then assigning them to variables in a struct.

Here is the code that is having issues:

```
unsigned long deltatime = 0;
unsigned long totaltime = 0;
unsigned char *sbyte = (unsigned char *)malloc(sizeof(unsigned char));
unsigned char meta_e;
    printf("\nTrack %d\n", i+1);
    n = 0;
    while (n<track[i].length)
    {
        sbyte[0] = 0;
        t += ReadVarLen(track[i].data, n, &deltatime);
        n += t;
        totaltime += deltatime; 
        if (t == 0) n++;
        memcpy(sbyte, &(track[i].data[n]), sizeof(unsigned char));
        printf("%lu\t %lu %.2X ",totaltime, deltatime, *sbyte);
        if (*sbyte >= 0xFF)
        {
            unsigned long length = 0;
            unsigned char *dta;
            meta_e = track[i].data[++n];
            printf("%.2X ", meta_e);
            n += ReadVarLen(track[i].data, ++n, &length);
            printf("%.2lX ", length);
            dta = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * length);
            memcpy(dta, &(track[i].data[++n]), length);
            for (j=0;j<length;j++) {printf("%.2X ",dta[j]);}
            n += length;
            printf("\n");
        } 
        if ((*sbyte >= 0x80) && (*sbyte < 0xF0))
        {
            if ((*sbyte >= 0x80) && (*sbyte < 0x90)) {
                unsigned char *midi_e;
                midi_e = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 2);
                memcpy(midi_e, &(track[i].data[++n]), 2);
                for (i=0;i<2;i++) printf("%.2X ",midi_e[i]);
                n += 2;
                printf("\n");
            }
            if ((*sbyte >= 0x90) && (*sbyte < 0xA0)) {
                char *midi_e;
                midi_e = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 2);
                memcpy(midi_e, &(track[i].data[++n]), 2);
                for (i=0;i<2;i++) printf("%.2X ",midi_e[i]);
                n += 2;
                printf("\n");
            }
            if ((*sbyte >= 0xA0) && (*sbyte < 0xB0)) {
                char *midi_e;
                midi_e = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 2);
                memcpy(midi_e, &(track[i].data[++n]), 2);
                for (i=0;i<2;i++) printf("%.2X ",midi_e[i]);
                n += 2;
                printf("\n");
            }
            if ((*sbyte >= 0xB0) && (*sbyte < 0xC0)) {
                char *midi_e;
                midi_e = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 2);
                memcpy(midi_e, &(track[i].data[++n]), 2);
                for (i=0;i<2;i++) printf("%.2X ",midi_e[i]);
                n += 2;
                printf("\n");
            }
            if ((*sbyte >= 0xC0) && (*sbyte < 0xD0)) {
                char *midi_e;
                midi_e = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char));
                memcpy(midi_e, &(track[i].data[++n]),1);
                printf("%.2X ",midi_e[0]);
                n++;
                printf("\n");
            }
            if ((*sbyte >= 0xD0) && (*sbyte < 0xE0)) {
                char *midi_e;
                midi_e = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char));
                memcpy(midi_e, &(track[i].data[++n]), 1);
                printf("%.2X ",midi_e[0]);
                n++;
                printf("\n");
            }
            if ((*sbyte >= 0xE0) && (*sbyte < 0xF0)) {
                char *midi_e;
                midi_e = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 2);
                memcpy(midi_e, &(track[i].data[++n]), 2);
                for (i=0;i<2;i++) printf("%.2X ",midi_e[i]);
                n += 2;
                printf("\n");
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

My output looks like this:

```
Track 1

0        0 FF 01 27 43 6F 6D 70 6F 73 65 64 20 41 6E 64 20 53 65 71 75 65 6E 63 65 64 20 42 79 20 4D 69 63 68 61 65 6C 20 53 68 69 72 6B 
0        0 FF 54 05 00 00 00 00 00 
0        0 FF 51 03 07 A1 20 
0        0 FF 58 04 04 02 18 08 
0        0 FF 59 02 00 00 
0        0 FF 2F 00 

Track 2

0        0 FF 21 01 00 
0        0 FF 20 01 03 
0        0 B3 07 7F 
0        0 C7 05 
1800     1800 08 1808    8 97 4D 50
```

This second to last line of output is the problem. It should be:

```
0        0 C3 44 81
```

According to a hex converter tool i used to inspect the sample MIDI file.

I've printed out the buffer byte by byte and it also says that value should be C3 not C7. It seems that only when I assign the value of the buffer to the variable sbyte does it change (inexplicably from my perspective) to 0xC7.

Comment: That's rather a lot of code to look at, and it doesn't mean much to us without the input file to go along with it. Please create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in order to get the best answers.

Comment: Am I missing something here? What is the point of allocating memory with `malloc`, and copying data with `memcpy` when the data size is 1 byte? Why not just declare `unsigned char sbyte`? I notice too you have not `free()`ed `sbyte` so you have a memory leak. Ditto for `midi_e`, you could just declare an array `unsigned char midi_e[2]` and simplify the code.

Comment: A program change event cannot have multiple data bytes; the `81` would be part of the following timestamp. The code you've shown looks OK (if incomplete); show the hexdump of the input file.

Answer (score 0):

It starts going wrong when you reach one of the lines that says:

```
for (i=0;i<2;i++) printf("%.2X ",midi_e[i]);
```

The problem is you're already using variable `i` outside the loop to index the track so you don't want to be changing its value here. Maybe use `j` instead?